# How to use lazy seq in :where clausule?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to solve riddle similar to the [Einstein's riddle](http://www.manbottle.com/trivia/einstein_s_riddle). To solve this I am using [library for making permutations](https://code.google.com/p/clojure-contrib/source/browse/trunk/src/clojure/contrib/combinatorics.clj?r=420)

First I define all permutations over subjects

```
(def auta (permutations [:Opel :Jeep :Renault :Octavia :Peaguot]))
(def skym (permutations [:pes :rodina :kamaradka :pratele :sam]))
(def mena (permutations [:Honza :Viktor :Marek :Ota :pavel]))
(def prace (permutations [:Student :Malir :Technik :Prog :nic]))
(def typ  (permutations [:Wherti :Myst :Multi :trad :earth]))
```

Next I make the list of matrix of solutions

```
(def all (for 
[a (doall auta) s (doall skym) m (doall mena) p (doall prace) t(doall typ)]
[a s m p t]))
```

This working as I want and I can print first item

```
(print (take 1 all))

This will show me:

([(:Opel :Jeep :Renault :Octavia :Peaguot) (:pes :rodina :kamaradka :pratele :sa
m) (:Honza :Viktor :Marek :Ota :pavel) (:Student :Malir :Technik :Prog :nic) (:W
herti :Myst :Multi :trad :earth)])nil
```

Now I want to add a conditions in for (at first I want to add condition that the :pavel is first name of permutation.

```
(def all (for 
[a (doall auta) s (doall skym) m (doall mena) p (doall prace) t(doall typ)
:when (= (m 1) :pavel) ]
[a s m p t]))
```

and I end with

```
CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be c
ast to clojure.lang.IFn, compiling:(C:\Users...
```

What I need t change in condition to make it running?

P.S.: I try to do thing like (doall m) etc. but it did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `permutations` returns a seq and you're trying to access the first element of that seq using `(m 1)` (which, btw, is also incorrect since indices start at 0). This, however, only works for vectors:

```
(def sq (range 1 5))
(def v  (vec sq))

(sq 1) ; => ClassCastException clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot ...
(v 1)  ; => 2
(v 0)  ; => 1 (this is the actual first element)
```

Solution: use `nth`:

```
(nth sq 0) ; => 1
(nth v 0)  ; => 1
```

Comment: Thank you for saving me. The :when (= (nth m 0) :pavel repairs it. I believed that permutations returns vector.